# Does periodicity imply uniformly recurrent?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

We have the following definitions:

> Let $X$ be a metric space, $T:X\rightarrow X$  continuous. We say that $x\in X$ is periodic if there exists $n_0\in \Bbb{N}$ s.t.  $T^n(x)=x$ .

> We say $x\in X$ is uniformly recurrent if for all $\epsilon >0~$ $\exists ~n_k\rightarrow \infty$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ s.t. $\sup_{k} |n_{k}-n_{k+1}|<\infty$ and $d(T^{n_k}x,x)<\epsilon$.

Now we have seen the so called [Thue-Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) sequence and proved that this is a sequence which is uniformly recurrent but not periodic.

Then I asked myself if it is true that periodicity implies uniformly recurrence?

My guess would be no, since in the above definition of uniformly recurrence one need $n_k\rightarrow \infty$, I think this is the "problem" that we do not have "periodicity $\Rightarrow$ uniformly recurrence". Because if we wouldn't have this assumption one could take $n_k=n_0$ and would be done, but with this assumption it is not possible to prove that "periodicity $\Rightarrow$ uniformly recurrence" or am I wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes, periodicity implies uniform recurrence".

It suffices to let $n_0$ be as in the definition of periodicity and then define $n_k = kn_0$.  Then $|n_k - n_{k+1}| = n_0$ and $d(T^{n_k}x,x) = 0$.

Comment: Ah wow I have not thought about that thanks a lot!!